# order of integrals with independent limits

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was wondering if the following is true assuming that the limits are independent (like constants)

$$  \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \int_{\gamma}^{\psi} {xy} dx dy = \int_{\gamma}^{\psi} \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} {xy} dy dx$$

I tried to google and checked the Wikipedia article and everything seems to refer to more complicated cases when there is dependence in the limits.

Thank you!

Comment: If the domain is bounded and the function is continuous on that domain then the function is integrable and you can apply Fubini, so i think that it is allowed to swap the integration order ;)

Comment: @Ale, yes, I was looking at that theorem as well. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $f(x,y)$ is integrable, Fubini's theorem states that
$$ \int_X \left(\int_Y f(x,y)\ dy\right)dx= \int_Y \left(\int_X f(x,y)\ dx\right)dy =\int_{X\times Y} f(x,y)\ d(x,y) $$
For your specific case, we have
$$ \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \int_{\gamma}^{\psi} xy\ dxdy= \int_{\gamma}^{\psi} \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} xy\ dydx $$
$$ \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \left(y\int_{\gamma}^{\psi} x\ dx\right)dy= \int_{\gamma}^{\psi} \left(x\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} y\ dy\right)dx $$
$$ \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \left(\frac{y}{2} (\psi^2-\gamma^2) \right)dy= \int_{\gamma}^{\psi} \left(\frac{x}{2} (\beta^2-\alpha^2) \right)dx $$
$$ \frac{1}{2} (\psi^2-\gamma^2) \int_{\alpha}^{\beta}y\ dy= \frac{1}{2} (\beta^2-\alpha^2) \int_{\gamma}^{\psi}x\ dx $$
$$ \frac{1}{4} (\psi^2-\gamma^2)(\beta^2-\alpha^2) = \frac{1}{4} (\psi^2-\gamma^2)(\beta^2-\alpha^2) $$
Thus
$$ \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \int_{\gamma}^{\psi} xy\ dxdy= \int_{\gamma}^{\psi} \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} xy\ dydx $$

Comment: I'm curious why this won't work then: in mathematica Integrate[
 Integrate[1/(E^((a - c)^2 + (b - c)^2) ), {c, 0, 1}], {b, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}] does not give the result, however, if I reverse the order, it works Integrate[
 Integrate[
  1/(E^((a - c)^2 + (b - c)^2) ), {b, -Infinity, Infinity}], {c, 0, 
  1}]